# recovering GRUB boot loader -

Tags: grub2, ppa

I'm just new in the Linux worlds, so please do not be too much technical and mean to me.

I have tried to install windows10 along my Ubuntu20.04 LTS. I have relided on the following video:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzbIckBnerg&list=WL&index=16&t=542s][1]
Everything goes smooth until the boot-repair installation in order to recover GRUB boot loader.
The command I have used is the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

The message given to me is the following:

```
    Simple tool to repair frequent boot problems.

Website: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo - Release amd64 (20190416) disco InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo - Release amd64 (20190416) disco Release
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu disco InRelease [15.4 kB]
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                 
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have no idea what it is going on. I would be very grateful if you help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using the Installer for Ubuntu 19.04 (which is End of Life) to do the job, that's the culprit.

According to https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair
no packages are provided for `disco` (19.04).

You'll need to download a recent version of Ubuntu from https://ubuntu.com/#download and create a new installer USB.

Comment: I did what you told. But then, when I try to install boot-repair it says:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair

Comment: Oops, I see, I should have checked the PPA first before posting an answer. Please see  my edit.